# Extract features using openface and opensmile videos

Tags: python, deep-learning, video-processing

I have MOSI videos. I want to Extract OpenFace features from the video clips.
Extract openSMILE features from the audio with creating pickle file,
Separate the train-valid-test subsets.Then , by defining a visual submodel on OpenFace inputs, an acoustic submodel on openSMILE inputs, then concatenate.

I tried extract features openface and opensmile videos. But I get an error. foldername: No such file or directory How can I solve this problem? thanks

```
for filename in os.listdir('MOSI/videos'):

print(filename)      # 输出每个文件夹的名字，逗号使输出不换行
print(" : ")
!./OpenFace/build/bin/FeatureExtraction -f filename -out_dir processed
!ffmpeg -y -loglevel info -i foldername smile
y = smile.process_file(filename)
```

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if you solved the problem? I am also interested in seeing a solution, thanks!

Comment: Hi I couldnt solve my problem :/